# Commiting a SQL db to github?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, github

Possibly newbie question.

I made an app (Postgres, Node, React) and I want to send it to somebody who can try it out with this little db that I made for it. Is there a way to do that? Googling has brought up a few seemingly positive results but none of them I've been able to apply to my application. Is there a resource I can look into (OS, VS environment)?

Comment: Convert the whole DB to a script and commit that? including the table creation, constraints, triggers, data, everything.

Comment: @crimson589 yeah, postgres has pg_dump, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Like [crimson589](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5797253/crimson589)'s comment you can create a db dump with all the sql used to create the database

```
pg_dump dbname > outfile
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/backup-dump.html

commit outfile to `git` or other version control

If you want to use github, create a repo via the web and it tells you how to add your code to the repo.